# Google Cloud Platform - Resource of type "Organisation"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, resources, namespace-organisation

I wanted to setup my cloud identity but its asking me to verify the domain that is already hosted on GCP. Can you help me with Cloud Identity setup with a proper organisation created (today its named "No Organisation"). I'm the admin for this account DOMAIN: we host our Corporate website on GCP with domain already registered with DNS services in google.

on the GCP Identity page its also giving me the following message.

- Your current account, k*****.***a@DOMAIN.NL, is not associated with an organization on Google Cloud. This checklist is designed for administrators who are trusted with complete control over a company’s Google Cloud resources. If you already have an administrator account for your organization, sign in with the account now. Or, ask your company administrator to start the checklist.

I guess I'm stuck in a Chicken-n-Egg problem.

Comment: Do I understand correct: You own a domain that is hosted in Cloud DNS and your website is hosted on GCP Compute engine ? Have you tried the steps from the "[how to verify the domain](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/verify-domain#how-do-i-verify)" documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Google Workspace account](https://workspace.google.com). Create it on your domain DOMAIN.NL, with you as 1st admin user and with subscription plan or not (in my case, I wasn't able to remove the 15 days of trial. Get it, you will be able to remove the trial subscription later (in the user list) on the admin.google.com Workspace console). *You are able to create your org for free, but it's absolutely not clear!!*

From the new user account that you have created on your Workspace domain (you@DOMAIN.NL), you will be able to reach the console (console.cloud.google.com) and you have your org.

Now you need to [migrate the projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) and to review the authorization. You also need to (re)create a Billing Account.

I didn't find another way to achieve this.

Comment: Tried the same but since the domain is already being used by the current project, Google stops me midway during the registration suggesting "The Domain name is already in use...."

As a follow up option it provides following instructing.
"This domain is already in use"
If you receive this message when trying to sign up for a Google service, it might be because:

You recently removed this domain from another managed Google account. It can take 24 hours (or 7 days if you purchased your account from a reseller) before you can use the domain with a new account which also doesnt work...

Comment: Arf, I didn't have this use case :(